# Caching functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How could you cache the execution of any function in JavaScript?

What if I'm passing more than one argument in a cached function?

Comment: What do you mean by _cache_?

Comment: **Please don't put your text in bold for no reason.** Please *do* state clearly what goal you're trying to accomplish:  [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Store the result of the function in a variable, just like in any language?  What are you trying to do and what isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a method where you will pass a function and it will internally maintain a cache object where calculated value will be cached. When you will call the function with same argument, the cached value will be served.

```
function cacheFn(fn) {
    var cache={};

    return function(arg){
        if (cache[arg]){
           return cache[arg];
        }
        else{
           cache[arg] = fn(arg);
            return cache[arg];
        }
    }
}
```

if you are passing more than one argument, first we have to use arguments to get all the parameters passed to the function and then we can generate key for the cache object. Generating key for the cache object could be tricky and one solution could be just get the all the parameters and concatenate those. Look at the code below.

```
return function(){
  var args = arguments;  
  var key = [].slice.call(args).join('');
  if(cache[key]){
      return cache[key];
  }
  else{
      cache[key] = fn.apply(thi, args);
      return cache[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: This assumes, of course, that the arguments can be meaningfully coerced to string.

Comment: There's a small bug here: If the function returns 0 for some input, then the cache will be ignored. `hasOwnProperty` should be used instead of checking for `cache[key]` to be falsy.